# How to add validation/restrictions for HTML5 date field without jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add validations/restrictions to date element using HTML api,without jquery?

I am currently using jquery datePicker to display calendar,and for adding restrictions using the beforeShow method of the datePicker.

Now i am trying to use the HTML5 calender and want to know how to add restrictions(eg:disable weendends/holidays) to the HTML5 calendar.
Can somebody point me in right direction?

Comment: Yes. Yes, it is. Seriously, though, we need more information if you want an actual answer other than 'yes.' What validation do you want to add? For what elements? What's your mark-up? What have you tried to do? What went wrong? Take a look at [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [guide to writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), to better help us to help you.

Comment: without jQuery - oh yes you can ... try native javascript! Server side PHP also does nice validation. Though what really are your specific needs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` attributes on your date input.

Spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

**Edit :**

- Afaik, there is no way to disable specific days using HTML5 date input...
- If you want to be cross-browser, use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and provide a fallback for old browsers (for example jQuery datePicker) : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-cross-browser-html5-forms/

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible to disable selection of specific dates ?

Comment: remember the old browsers that don't support html5! ...unfortunately which most people use.