# html 5 date input element is not parsed

Tags: html, date, input

Sorry if that question was asked but i was unable to find exact duplicate. I want to have HTML 5 date control that is initialized with date - 19 May 1992. I have tried the following:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field BirthDate must be a date." data-val-required="The BirthDate field is required." id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="date" value="5/19/1992" />
```

But it's not working. Could anybody give me the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574442/how-to-add-validation-restrictions-for-html5-date-field-without-jquery-javascrip

Comment: that doesn't answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) compatible format like `1992-05-19`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kEFd4/

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem. However I noticed that datePicker works in chrome and doesn't work in IE v9.0. So I think it's better to use jQuery DatePicker, not HTML 5 one