# Datepicker for Date of Birth input field restriction to show future dates in HTML

Tags: html, datepicker

I am using input field as a Datepicker for Date of birth, But I want it to restrict to show only past dates. 
How can I implement it in HTML.

Here is the piece of code.

`<input class="inputStyle" type="date" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date">`

Comment: Please use bootstrap datepicker for more functionality

Comment: @mplungjan: After the latest edit, this question now appears to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574442/how-to-add-validation-restrictions-for-html5-date-field-without-jquery-javascrip).