# ASP .Net Core Date Range Validation

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a scenario where I need to allow user to only select dates between a range. My code is as below. If the `Field.Name` contains `Date` keyword, I display the `datepicker`. Is there a way I can validate the date range within the `if` condition or I would have to use some kind of `JS` to validate?

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fields.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    @{
                        if (Model.Fields[i].Name.ToString().Contains("Date"))
                        {
                            <input type="date" asp-for="Fields[i].Value" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Fields[i].Value" />
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Any guidence would greatly help..

Comment: If you POST data to your back-end (ASP) you could do validation there.  If you want the user to know it's not valid before submitting you'll need Javascript/AJAX in some fashion.

Comment: You can use the `min` and `max` attributes to limit the date https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574600/2030565. Many datepickers allow you to limit the date range as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,you can refer to [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date),Secondly you can use onchange="xxx".Here is a worked demo:

View:

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="date" name="date1" id="date1" min="2020-01-01" max="2020-12-31"/>
    <input type="date" name="date2" id="date2" onchange="compare(this)" />
</div>
@section scripts{ 
<script>
    function compare(item) {
        if (new Date($(item).val()) > new Date("2020-7-14")) {
            $(item).attr("value", "");
            $("#date2").remove();
            var date2 = '<input type="date" name="date2" id="date2"  onchange="compare(this)" />';
            $("#div1").append(date2);
        }

    }
</script>

}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to find a solution with your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code with guidance from `Yiyi You`.

````
DateTime dtValidFromDate = dtInputDate.AddDays(-3);
DateTime dtValidToDate = dtInputDate.AddDays(1);
string strInputDate = dtInputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string strValidFromDate = dtValidFromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string strValidToDate = dtValidToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
<input type="@Model.Fields[i].Type" asp-for="Fields[i].Value"
   value="@strInputDate" min="@strValidFromDate" max="@strValidToDate"/>```
````